# What naming scheme should I use for passing data to MySQL table with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an HTML form with a few different sections of data that are pulled from a database (Section1, Section2, etc.). The data in each of these tables correlates to a table from my MySQL database. I'll explain what I'm trying to do the best that I can.

When I hover the mouse over a field in any of the sections, a checkbox is dynamically added to that field data which allows me to choose that particular string of data for editing later. After choosing what fields I want to edit I click on a button on the form which brings up a modal window that includes labels and text input boxes where I can make my changes. Finally, after this I click on a button on the modal window to save and apply my changes to the database using an AJAX call.

So essentially the process goes like this: `[mouseover] => [choose to edit] => [open window for editing] => [make changes] => [apply changes to db]`.

I am using XAMPP with PHP 5.5.9, MySQL, and JQuery/Javascript.

How should I specify what database table the data I want to edit belongs to in the modal window and apply to my database without giving away my table names in the HTML or JavaScript code?

Comment: i think you should look on localStorage or IndexedBD for doing all on the same page and memorize changed line.

Comment: Interesting, I'm familiar with localStorage but somehow I haven't heard of IndexedBD.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/ is hepfull for begin and understand.

Comment: interesting link, but how does that hide the table names used on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make up a name for each table and place it into an array on the server side that converts the value on the client side. Something like this:

```
php

$arrTable = array();
$arrTable["someName_01"] = "user";
$arrTable["someName_02"] = "products";
$arrTable["someName_03"] = "cost";
$arrTable["someName_04"] = "orders";




html 

<input type="text" value="" id="someName_01">
```

Comment: Correct me if I don't understand correctly, but is each $arrTable["someName_xx"] an array? And each array should only hold data for the table that it's referencing?

Comment: your $_POST will have the table name you made up so post name is what you are a looking at

Comment: foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
$query = "insert into " . $arrTable["key"] . " values (" . $value . ");";

//
//more code needed here
// 

}

Comment: Currently I'm trying to do this with a single AJAX call. I'm assuming I'll need to send a request for each different table?

Comment: try looping your current `$_POST` variable, `foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
echo = $key . " = . " $value . "</br>";
}`